# convert gray images to rgb images and replace it by imread() in matlab

Tags: python, image, matlab, image-processing

I have a dataset including 15k gray images

I need to train the Alexnet -pretrained model- by the dataset in matlab. But Alexnet accepts RBG images with size [227 * 227 * 3]

is it possible to convert a gray image to a RGB image?

I have tried this code

```
 im = imread(filename);
    im = imresize(im,[227,227]);
    RGB_Image = cat(3, im,im,im);
    imshow(filename);
```

But I found this Error:

```
Multi-plane image inputs must be RGB images of size MxNx3.
```

Comment: Please show the full error message, including the stack trace. Knowing *where* the error occurred is just as important as knowing the message itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the more broad aspect of color spaces it is not possible to convert grey images to rgb. But you only want to represent a data structure of [227,227,1] to a data structure of [227,227,3].

The original OP code do as following. imread returns an array of the size 227,227,3. Then imresize will return again a 227,227,3 array. Eventually cat will recreate a 227,227,9 array. Therefore we need to cast the data structure after the imread.

in matlab:

```
 im = imread(filename);
 im = rgb2gray(im);
 rgb_im = repmat(im, [1, 1, 3]); % or cat(3,im,im,im)
 imshow(rgb_im);
```

in python:

```
im = matplotlib.pyplot.imread(filename)
im.resize([227,227,1])
rgb_im = numpy.matlib.reshape(numpy.matlib.repmat(im, 1, 3),[227,227,3])
matplotlib.pyplot.imshow(rgb_im)
```

Comment: “it is not possible to convert grey images to rgb” — yes, it is possible.

Comment: Also, how is the `repmat` different from OP’s `cat` solution? The result should be identical.

Comment: If you use the "dim" param in cat correctly there shouldn't be a difference. The OP got the dim param right. imread returns an array of the size 227,227,3. Then imresize will return again a 227,227,3 array. Eventually cat will recreate a 227,227,9 array.

Comment: Yep, that’s a good explanation. Why don’t you write that in your answer? Then you provide content that educates, and is worth upvoting. I think the best answers explain why the error message happens, and why the proposed solution works.